# Problem with a seemingly simple 2-way ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, biostatistics

I want to test for the effects of two factors ('Habitat' and 'Population') on a continuous variable ('Trait'). I'm using R to call this seemingly simple 2-way ANOVA:

```
model <- lm(Trait ~ Population + Habitat, data=d)
summary(model)
```

However, I don't get an effect for 'Habitat'. I don't really understand why, because when adding 'Population' instead as a co-variate in a mixed-model, I do get an effect for 'Habitat'. Why is my simple
2-way ANOVA not working, and how can I fix this problem (in R)?

```
structure(list(ID = structure(1:150, .Label = c("ID001", "ID002", 
"ID003", "ID004", "ID005", "ID006", "ID007", "ID008", "ID009", 
"ID010", "ID011", "ID012", "ID013", "ID014", "ID015", "ID016", 
"ID017", "ID018", "ID019", "ID020", "ID021", "ID022", "ID023", 
"ID024", "ID025", "ID026", "ID027", "ID028", "ID029", "ID030", 
"ID031", "ID032", "ID033", "ID034", "ID035", "ID036", "ID037", 
"ID038", "ID039", "ID040", "ID041", "ID042", "ID043", "ID044", 
"ID045", "ID046", "ID047", "ID048", "ID049", "ID050", "ID051", 
"ID052", "ID053", "ID054", "ID055", "ID056", "ID057", "ID058", 
"ID059", "ID060", "ID061", "ID062", "ID063", "ID064", "ID065", 
"ID066", "ID067", "ID068", "ID069", "ID070", "ID071", "ID072", 
"ID073", "ID074", "ID075", "ID076", "ID077", "ID078", "ID079", 
"ID080", "ID081", "ID082", "ID083", "ID084", "ID085", "ID086", 
"ID087", "ID088", "ID089", "ID090", "ID091", "ID092", "ID093", 
"ID094", "ID095", "ID096", "ID097", "ID098", "ID099", "ID100", 
"ID101", "ID102", "ID103", "ID104", "ID105", "ID106", "ID107", 
"ID108", "ID109", "ID110", "ID111", "ID112", "ID113", "ID114", 
"ID115", "ID116", "ID117", "ID118", "ID119", "ID120", "ID121", 
"ID122", "ID123", "ID124", "ID125", "ID126", "ID127", "ID128", 
"ID129", "ID130", "ID131", "ID132", "ID133", "ID134", "ID135", 
"ID136", "ID137", "ID138", "ID139", "ID140", "ID141", "ID142", 
"ID143", "ID144", "ID145", "ID146", "ID147", "ID148", "ID149", 
"ID150"), class = "factor"), Population = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), class = "factor"), 
    Habitat = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("marine", "stream"), class = "factor"), 
    Sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    Trait = c(15L, 15L, 15L, 10L, 14L, 12L, 15L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 
    14L, 16L, 15L, 16L, 11L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 11L, 14L, 11L, 13L, 
    17L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 11L, 17L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
    11L, 9L, 11L, 10L, 14L, 13L, 10L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 13L, 
    12L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 12L, 10L, 
    12L, 11L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 18L, 13L, 12L, 
    11L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 
    15L, 13L, 14L, 16L, 17L, 13L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 16L, 15L, 15L, 
    13L, 12L, 13L, 12L, 16L, 16L, 13L, 13L, 16L, 13L, 16L, 11L, 
    15L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 13L, 11L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 10L, 15L, 9L, 
    12L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 11L, 16L, 
    14L, 14L, 13L, 13L, 12L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 16L, 18L, 13L, 
    12L, 14L, 16L, 14L, 13L, 10L, 9L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-150L))
```

Comment: Since I ave not gotten a reply yet, I wonder whether I need to provide more information? I'm sure this is a relatively simple issue for a statistics-savey person.

Comment: Please give context, describe the research question, show us some plots, ...

Answer (score 5):

This is your problem

```
> with(d, table(Population, Habitat))
          Habitat
Population marine stream
         A     20      0
         B      0     40
         C     20      0
         D      0     40
         E      0     30
```

For any population there is only one habitat, so it's not possible to estimate differences by population and by habitat -- in experimental design jargon, they are 'completely confounded'

Comment: Thank you for this. I had the notion that this was the problem. However, how then would you test correctly for an effect of 'habitat', while accounting for the fact that there might be population-specific effects? Would you go with a LMM, with 'habitat' as the explanatory variable of 'trait', and by specifying 'population' as the random effect? Maybe my problem with this is that I would expect 'population' to have an effect, so I find it weird to specify it as a 'random effect'.

Comment: I'd specify population as a random effect; that's basically the only way you could extract any information about Habitat while still trying to adjust for population